# logging request and response while using netsuite suitetalk

Tags: netsuite

is it possible to print/log the request response while using the Netsuite API, is there any property we need to set in the nsclient.properties file that might help.
I am trying to find this so that while integrating with NetSuite, in case of any issues, I don't have to go check the API request/response logs in NetSuite.

regards,
Moin

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I'm not pretty sure that there is any inbuilt feature in NetSuite that allows you to log the request and response of your deployed `Restlet`. In Netsuite there is a method called :

```
nlapiLogExecution(logType, title, details)
```

Which you can use for temporal logging/Debugging. However, it doesn't persist your logging data permanently, so you can't use the same later. Yeah, Of-course you can find many workarounds to get your task done. Create a custom record with appropriate fields for logging then inside your restlet you can write the code to create a log file for each req/resp.

Answer (score 1):

Requests and responses are logged within NetSuite itself. You need to have the Admin role to see them.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more information on this. Where can I get all the request response of my deployed Restlet inside Netsuite with Admin role ?

Comment: Are you using RESTLet or SuiteTalk? They are 2 different things. RESTLets you can log using nlapiLogExecution. SuiteTalk is logged automatically under the Setup -> Integration menu.

Comment: yes, requests and response can be found in NetSuite, but while using the NS API to integrate NS data to our system, often we feel the need to check the request/response that we get back from NS.  We know we get the response, but its a response object which we would need to parse, instead I was looking if there is a configuration or logging option while using suitetalk wherein I can log the raw request/response.

Comment: Are you using PHP and the PHP Toolkit? If so, add a folder called nslog to the PHPToolkit directory. You'll get all the raw requests and responses in there.

Comment: I am using Netsuite SuiteTalk Java API. Can I still get the request/response for the API calls ?

Comment: In my version of Netsuite (system.netsuite.com), the logs can be found in 

Setup | Integration | Web Services Usage Log